# Existing Complex data structures

Tags: java

is there a data structure like a set which can take different types as parameters? or do I have to create my own class? 
an example to clarify...something like

DataStructure  mydatastruct = new DataStructure   ()

I'm I asking too much? :P

I meant something like this..I dont know why is not showing like I'm actually writing it

```
DataStructure <type1, type2, type3,...> mydatastruct = new DataStructure <String, Integer, String> ()
```

Comment: I meant something like this..I dont know why is not showing like I'm actually writing it 
DataStructure <type1, type2, type3,...> mydatastruct = new DataStructure  <String, Integer, String> ()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are called [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean the datastructure called `tuple` in other languages. They don't exist in Java.

In C++ you have the generic (aka. template) class called `pair` which implements your example above for 2 types, but this doesn't exist either in Java. However it is pretty easy to implement it yourself if you need such functionality often.